# Redrawing Jbutton in java Swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I've made a Jbutton with a background image. The problem is,background image is circle while Jbutton is printed square. Is there a way to redraw Jbutton as a circle?

Comment: Try this: http://java-swing-tips.blogspot.co.uk/2008/07/create-round-image-jbutton.html

Comment: this is possible with standard methods implemented in JButtons API (undecorated JButtons), isn't required any changes wiht shapes